# What is the Chomsky level of pattern matching?

Tags: chomsky-hierarchy

Pattern matching in programming languages as for example in [Racket](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/match.html) is some kind of parsing. Which level in the Chomsky hierarchy does this parsing technique have? Is it type-3 like regular expressions or type-2 or even lower?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what types of patterns are supported.  If it is only classical regular expressions, as in theoretical computer science, it is the regular languages.  If it is Perl-compatible regular expressions (PCRE), then it is the context-sensitive languages; see [Which languages do Perl-compatible regular expressions recognize?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/4839/755).

See also [When is a regexp not a Regular Expression?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/38451/755) and [Expressiveness of modern regular expressions](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/24031/755) and [How much more powerful are regexes in modern programming languages compared to regular expressions from the theory of computation?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/120481/755) and [What can be proven regarding the differences in power between unary ECMAScript regex functions and primitive recursive functions?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/137112/755).